# java namespace collisions

Tags: java, namespaces, scope

I find myself frequently making the following error.

```
public class Foo{

  Bar bar;

  public void doSomething(){
    Bar bar = makeNewBar();
    // bla bla
  }

}
```

where the error is that I want to set Foo's bar, not a local Bar. I.e, I should say `bar = makeNewBar()`, not `Bar bar = makeNewBar()`. Is there a compiler warning flag or something that can detect "namespace collisions" like this? If not, what's a good way to avoid this (short of not making the error, which is obviously the best option =p)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a compiler warning, but any decent IDE should show you the fact that the local variable hides the instance variable...

Comment: Use an IDE; they tell you these things.

Comment: [Checkstyle can detect this.](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#HiddenField)

Comment: Looks like Eclipse has a setting for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122959/usage-of-eclipse-warning-field-declaration-hides-another-field-or-variable

Answer (score 5):

That's not really the job of the compiler but most IDE warn you with correct settings if you shadow a variable.

Using Eclipse, go to `Preferences / Java / Compiler / Error/Warnings` and look for `Name shadowing and conflicts`.

Comment: In Netbeans it's a hint called "Local Variable Hides a Field": Tools > Options > Editor > Hints > General > "Local Variable Hides a Field"

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use

```
this.bar = makeNewBar();
```

(That will be less confusing to the reader of the class also..)

---

(OR)

This URL shows that Eclipse can be configured to warn about declarations that hide class members:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm

See the section on "Field declaration hides another field or variable"

The documentation states that this warning is defaulted (in ECLIPSE) to IGNORE, so you are right in that it would have to be explicitly set.

Comment: Of course he could. That falls under "Not making the error in the first place".