# Print numbers sequentially using two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This an interview question and i don't think it has any relation with practical real life problems.
I have to print numbers 12345.... sequentially but the condition is i have to print it using two threads one responsible for printing odd numbers and one for even numbers. 
till now i have come up with this solution.

```
    package junk.concurrency;

public class PrintEvenOddTester {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TaskEvenOdd t = new TaskEvenOdd(10);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t, "odd printer");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t, "even printer");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {

    private int max;
    private boolean isOdd = true;
    private int number = 1;

    TaskEvenOdd(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    synchronized void printEven(int number) { // sync on runnable itself

        while (isOdd) { // if odd is to be printed, wait
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even:" + this.number);  // LINE-1
        isOdd = true;
        this.number++;                             // LINE-2
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void printOdd(int number) { // sync on runnable itself
        while (!isOdd) { // if even is to be printed, wait
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Odd:" + this.number);    // LINE-3
        this.number++;                               // LINE-4
        isOdd = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (number <= max) {

            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("even printer")) {
                printEven(number);
            } else {
                printOdd(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**1**
while writing this code i observed one strange behaviour which i did not understand. If at LINE-1,2,3,4 in above code, i write `number` instead of `this.number` my number instance variable is not getting incremented and code just prints infinite number of 1s. 
I assume both the `printEven` and `printOdd` method is called on runnable instance itself then why its value is not getting incremented. I tried making `number` volatile but still it resulted in same output.
 
**2**
Also i see numbers are getting printed till 11 not till 10. I understand why this is happening(as the last call to printOdd gets notified by last call of printEven(which is printing 10) thus prints 11 ), one way to avoid this is to check number every time before printing and see if it's under limit but i wanted to know what would be the best way to overcome this.
Thanks.

**EDIT** method parameter `number` is completely redundant and can be omitted. This if(this.max>=number) condition can be used before printing the number.

Comment: If I ever ask that question in an interview, the answer I want is, "That's a really dumb thing to do.  If you want any program to do a sequence of things in a particular order, the right way to make that happen is to do all of the things in _one thread_."  If anybody ever _asks_ me that question, and then says, "OK, but do it anyway," I will create a general solution where any number of threads take turns by handing off a token from one to the other through `BlockingQueues` :  When a thread receives the token, its it's turn.  When it's done, it hands the token to the next thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1

Your problem is that the parameter of your method is called **number** too. So it is **shadowing** the field of your class! So, when you omit, you inc the parameter; which simply doesn't have any real effect!

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Simply avoid doing it (so, by convention avoid using the same names as parameters and fields).
2. Use tooling that spots such problems and tells you about. For example, findbugs has explicit [rule](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE_SHADOWS_FIELD) to tell you about shadowing. And probably IDE's can be told to warn about this, too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122959/usage-of-eclipse-warning-field-declaration-hides-another-field-or-variable).

### 2

Given the fact that this is just a "simple" assignment ... in my opinion a simple check for the "limit" of the overall class would be just fine.

Comment: I'm wondering how i didn't observe such a small thing.. Well Thanks for pointing this out. Can you please comment on second part of question.

Comment: "use tooling that spots such problems and tells you about" could you please elaborate this point. Also if other solutions are possible for case-2 please let me know.

Comment: Added examples for such tooling.